# HOW to retrieve data using Joins in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I'm Looking fr something like this:

```
Table 1:

Column-A  C-B C-C
1          1   1
2          5   2
4          3   2

Table 2:

Column-D  C-E 
1          3 
7          9  
6          5  


result set:


1   1
2   5
4   3
1   3
7   9
6   5
```

Comment: provide the data in table structure...the details given by you is not understandable

Comment: Not nearly enough information.

Answer (score 2):

```
select columnA, C-b from table1
union all
select columnD, C-E from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           select column1,column2 from tablename1
          union all 
          select column3,column4 from tablename2
```

Comment: Hey, but no. of columns r not equal in those case na..??

How can we go wit dat..??